# Creating a file based on the byte() in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am retrieving an image from the SQL database into Byte() variable in VB.NET.

```
Dim img as byte() = dr(0)
```

How do I create a file in my C:\images\ directory from the above img.

I want to read the img and then create a file with name bimage.gif.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `File.WriteAllBytes`

```
Dim img as byte()=dr(0)
File.WriteAllBytes("C:/images/whatever.gif", img)
```

Comment: It's still weird to me how forward slashes work the same as backslashes in Windows now (unless it's always been that way).

Comment: @MusiGenesis, agreed, afaik not everything supports forward slashes, but .NET does and they doesn't require escaping.

Answer (score 4):

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\whatever.txt", bytes)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Dim ms as MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(img)
Dim bmp as Bitmap = CType(Bitmap.FromStream(ms), Bitmap)

bmp.Save(@"C:\images\name.gif", ImageFormat.Gif);

bmp.Dispose()
ms.Dispose()
```