# VB.NET retrieving varbinary data into picture box

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, picturebox

I have a some data in SQL Server in a `VARBINARY` column, I just want to know how to display it into a `PictureBox` in VB.NET. How to do this?

Binary data looks something like:

```
0x1F8B0800000000000400EDBD07601C499625262F6DCA7B7F4AF54AD7E.....(and a great many more bytes to come)......
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve VARBINARY values from SQL Server 2008 using VB.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613214/how-to-retrieve-varbinary-values-from-sql-server-2008-using-vb-net)

Comment: but the link that you gave doesn't show how to display the varbinary data into picturebox on VB.NET, can you explain to me the step by step process of displaying it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
  Private Sub sample()
    Dim command, commandReader As New NpgsqlCommand
    command.Connection = GetConnection()
    command.CommandText = "select imgField from imgtable"
    Dim productImageByte As Byte() = TryCast(command.ExecuteScalar, Byte())
    If productImageByte IsNot Nothing Then
        Using productImageStream As Stream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(productImageByte)
            PPicBoxPhoto.Image = Image.FromStream(productImageStream)
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

NOTE : *This a sample of my code that I'm using for my requirement, using* `PostgreSQL` *database and the image data type is*  `bytea`