# Retrieve VARBINARY from SQL Server table using FileStream to save file in VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, filestream, varbinary

I have stored data in a SQL Server table and I need to retrieve it through `FileStream` to save it back as a png picture as it was before.

I can't understand or find a way to do this, I read many suggestions and examples but none worked. Any ideas?

I just need an easy working solution, all the understanding can come later. Also, is it possible to do it with OleDb instead of T-SQL?

What I did to store the data is:

```
    Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(MyConnString)
    Dim command As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Prodotti SET Immagine = ? WHERE Oggetto = 'Monitor'", connection)
    Using picture As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Nuova cartella\galar 1 mainland.png")
        Using stream As New MemoryStream
            picture.Save(stream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
            command.Parameters.Add("@Picture", OleDbType.VarBinary).Value = stream.GetBuffer()
            connection.Open()
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            connection.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
```

What I got is in fact the Cell field as a long byte value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VB.NET retrieving varbinary data into picture box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263183/vb-net-retrieving-varbinary-data-into-picture-box)

Comment: Generally, storing a file in the database isn't the right idea in teh first place; why do you want to do this? You would be "better" off storing a path to the file in the database and saving it at that path.

Comment: I have to do this at work, we don't need to store the file paths but the data itself (were it not so, it would be much easier to do). Also, while I admit I didn't read that question yet, no, it didn't help, sadly. I need to save the file back, not to display it in a PictureBox.

Comment: i don't know vb.net too well, but aren't you just supposed to select the Immagine field from your table and then retrieve the byte array and save it to a file? I'm pretty sure someone already asked for that here

Comment: That's kinda what i have to do but I don't know how and can't find a single working example of code to do that with FileStream.

Comment: Out of curiosity why are you using `OleDbCommand` and `SqlCommand` etc?

Comment: To interact with SQL Server DB tables (?).

Comment: Not sure what you mean: SQL Server is designed to work with SqlCommand, the OleDb driver is compatibility only.

Comment: _That's kinda what i have to do but I don't know how and can't find a single working example of code to do that with FileStream_: Unfortunately, that's what happens when posts don't receive upvotes. The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66616751/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/70321177/10024425

Comment: Wait I'm confused: do you want to *save* a file to SQL Server, or do you want to *save* a picture from a PictureBox without an intermediate file, or do you want to *retrieve* the varbinary from SQL Server and save to a file or a PictureBox?

Comment: I have the stored file in the table, I need to get it back and save directly it back as a png picture as it was from the beginning, provided a dir path. Like, it was on Desktop\New Folder, i'm about to retrieve it back and save it in Desktop.

Comment: if you're using SQL Server, you will get better results using the SqClient library instead of the OleDb library. OleDb can still work, but you lose a tiny bit of performance for the abstraction layer (VERY small... you're unlikely to notice, but it IS there), as well as miss out on a few features, and you only get generic instead of exact error messages.

Comment: Probably right but we're using it as it has compatibility with also other contexts, like Access and others.

Comment: @grimoiredark no it hasn't and frankly, you don't.. You need a completely different driver for Access. And you use ADO.NET, not OLEDB to connect to *any* database. What you actually do is, instead of connecting to SQL Server directly from ADO.NET, you go from ADO.NET to OLEDB and only then connect to SQL server using a very old driver

Comment: Don't ask me, I'm new, until 2 weeks ago I never actually even worked with DBs lol so I have to stick with also suggestions, tasks and such that I receive from them! I mean, I can't doubt you but I'm not in the position to say anything for now!

Answer (score 6):

You don't even need an `Image` and `MemoryStream` here, because you are just getting it straight from a file. Just use a `FileStream` directly.

You should also pass `-1` as the length (ie a `max` value), otherwise you could end up with a different query plan for every execution.

```vb
Using
  connection As New SqlConnection(MyConnString),
  command As New SqlCommand("UPDATE Prodotti SET Immagine = @Picture WHERE Oggetto = 'Monitor'", connection),
  stream As FileStream = File.Open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Nuova cartella\galar 1 mainland.png")
    command.Parameters.Add("@Picture", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = stream
    connection.Open()
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Use `SqlCommand` etc rather than OleDb, as it is designed for SQL Server. If you need to support multiple DBMSs then use the `DbConnection` base type as an abstraction.

To do the same thing in reverse, use a reader. Since you only have one value, you can just do a single `Read` and then use `GetStream`

```vb
Using
  connection As New SqlConnection(MyConnString),
  command As New SqlCommand("SELECT Immagine FROM Prodotti WHERE Oggetto = 'Monitor'", connection),
  filestream As FileStream = File.OpenWrite("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Nuova cartella\galar 1 mainland.png")
    connection.Open()
    Using reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        If Not reader.Read() Then Return

        Using stream As Stream = reader.GetStream(0)
            stream.CopyTo(fileStream)
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Yes, correct. While I appreciate the suggestion from @Charlieface, that's not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Also, I have to use OleDb as here at work they mainly use that so I just have to get used to use that.

Comment: @siggemannen: If one doesn't store the data correctly, one can't retrieve usable data.

Comment: @Charlieface your solution worked perfectly. As stated above, I had to just change Sql to OleDb but it seems to work just fine, I'll try a few tests on other files but thank you very much so far, I've searched all day for a solution!

Comment: I *still* think you should target SqlClient. You could use the `DbConnection` and `DbCommand` etc base types if you want to abstract it out.

Comment: @Charlieface: You may consider adding an explanation why one should _pass -1 as the length_. It's unclear, to those who may not know, why this would be necessary.

Comment: If I may, I noticed an issue: the file I get back from the DB is kinda double size compared to the original file. What can be its cause?

Comment: Probably because you inserted it incorrectly in the first place, because you passed the whole buffer rather than just the bytes you wrote.

Comment: Idk, I tried to copy the full value from the table into a txt file. The original pic is 64.9 KB, while the txt file is 63.9 KB, the pic-from-db saved file instead is 128 KB...

Comment: Like I said, the full value was written using the original incorrect code, which was saving the whole buffer.

Comment: What would you suggest to do otherwise? I'm sincerely asking since I'm currently learning.

Comment: The first part of my answer shows how to do the insert correctly. If you want to fix it withou reinserting everything, you are going to need to look through each file and truncate at the last non-`NUL`  character.

Comment: I'll check better tomorrow but thank you for now!!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I don't see much of a reason to use a file stream here.

So, to insert the file, then this code can work:
(and I 100% agree that you should try and consider to move from the oleDB provider over to the SQL provider. However, existing code and existing systems are often not our choice as a developer).

So, to save the file into database, then this code:

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click

    Dim sFile As String =
        "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Nuova cartella\galar 1 mainland.png"

    Using conn = New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)

        Dim strSQL As String =
            "UPDATE Prodotti Set Immagine = @Image 
            WHERE Oggetto = 'Monitor'"

        Using cmdSQL = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)

            Dim RawFile As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(sFile)

            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Image", OleDbType.VarBinary).Value = RawFile

            conn.Open()
            cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End Using

    End Using

End Sub
```

And to pull the file, and save to disk from the database, then this code should suffice:

```
Sub WriteFile()
    Dim sFile As String =
        "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Nuova cartella\galar 1 mainland2.png"

    Using conn = New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)

        Dim strSQL As String =
            "SELECT Immagine FROM Prodotti 
            WHERE Oggetto = 'Monitor'"

        Using cmdSQL = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)

            conn.Open()
            Dim RawFile As Byte() = cmdSQL.ExecuteScalar
            File.WriteAllBytes(sFile, RawFile)

        End Using

    End Using

End Sub
```

Keep in mind that if you overwriting a existing file, then the file size does not reduce, and thus you might consider deleting the file before you WriteAllBytes out to such a file, else it will continue to show the old previous file size.

The above code is "file type" neutral, and it thus don't matter if you writing out a PDF file, or some image file

Comment: *"I see ZERO reason to use any file steam here at all"*. I was assuming that the OP was talking about the FILESTREAM feature in SQL Server, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Ah, ok then. No worries - we can let the dust settle here - I will (did) change "zero" to "not much" reason.......