# SQL Server VarBinary to VB Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, converters, varbinary

I have a table in SQL Server that has a number of columns. One of these columns is a `varbinary(4000)`.

Essentially I need to take several rows in the table and use the values in the columns. This includes the `varbinary(4000)` value. However I am having trouble passing the `varbinary(4000)` value into a VB parameter.

I need to be able to pass it into a parameter (the parameter types doesn't matter as long as I can compare it to other `varbinary(4000)` values (also taken from the same column in the DB)) and then send an update back to SQL Server a different table.

The `varbinary(4000)` values is being used as our primary key so obviously the value has to be the same when SQL Server receives it again.

I have tried a few different things. I believe that the `varbinary(4000)` value is a hexadecimal number.

```
TryCast(ds.Tables(0)("columnName"), System.Data.Linq.Binary).ToArray()
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ds.Tables(0)("columnName"))
Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ds.Tables(0)("columnName"));
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ds.Tables(0)("columnName"));
```

**Edit**

The possible duplication is not a solution because he simply needs to read the value from SQL. I need to compare it to other `varbinary(4000)` in the table in order to use the `varbinary(4000)` as a value in a sql insert command. Thus I need the `varbinary(4000)` value to be the same as when I received it (if it needs to be converted in between that's fine).

Comment: I would think that `varbinary` is... binary?  Perhaps `Dim data() As Byte = ds.Tables(0).Field(Of Byte())("columnName")`.  Not sure that's a great choice for a primary key.

Comment: As Mark said, `Byte()` is the appropriate type here. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425389/c-sharp-equivalent-of-sql-server-datatypes) is a nice overview of all types and their .NET equivalents.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve VARBINARY values from SQL Server 2008 using VB.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613214/how-to-retrieve-varbinary-values-from-sql-server-2008-using-vb-net)

Comment: `varbinary(4000)` as a primary key? Why? It will fail if you insert values over 900 bytes anyway.

Comment: Not my decision (and like you not my preference). This is the way they set up the database before I began working with it. I would obviously rather use an Integer because of simplicity but I am stuck to work with what they gave me.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across a couple of things. A Hashtable will hold the `varbinary` value. It can then be used as needed.

```
 Dim table As New Hashtable
 Dim ds As DataSet
 Dim count As Integer = 0

 'ds now holds the table with the varbinary column'
 ds = getSqlTable()

 For Each row In ds.Tables(0).Rows
   table(count) = row("varBinaryColumn")
   count += 1
 Next
```

Uploading it back to SQL can be done by.

```
 For Each item In table
    Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand
    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@binaryValue", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 8000).Value = item.Value
 Next
```